# Set drop down option with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

For this page: https://big.four51ordercloud.com/demo/product/customimageselector

I am trying to make one of several links that when clicked, will set the "Color" drop down to a certain value, such as "Style 1 - White" all while the "Color" drop down is hidden.

Example: Click HERE for White.

I can do this with jQuery and vanilla JavaScript just fine, but it doesn't work with AngularJS at all. The first drop down "Style" will dictate which hyperlinks are shown. That part I can do.

With that said, I am new to AngularJS.

Any advice? :-(

Comment: It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916967/set-default-value-for-dropdownlist-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows.

HTML

```
<button ng-click="chooseWhite()"></button>
<select ng-options="option in options" ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.options = [{ color: 'red', id: 1 }, { color: 'white', id: 2 }];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[0];
$scope.chooseWhite = function () {
  $scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];
};
```

Bind an object the `select` element and change the selected value while you click on links or buttons.